# In Django, how to implement foreign key relations between tables in different mysql dbs

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, foreign-key-relationship

In MySQL, we can have foreign key relationships between tables in different databases. I am finding it difficult to translate this relationship on the respective Django models.

I have read in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#cross-database-relations) that cross-db relationships are not supported, but can we override some property/function so that we can make tables be identified as `DB.table` rather than `table`?

For example, there is table `table1` in `DB1` that gets referenced in some `table2` in `DB2`. Django tries (unsuccessfully) to find `table1` in `DB2`, and raises a `DatabaseError`

```
Variable    Value
charset     'latin1'
exc         <class '_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError'>
self        <MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x2a87ed0>
args        (195,)
db          <weakproxy at 0x2a95208 to Connection at 0xdad0>
value       ProgrammingError(1146, "Table 'DB2.table1' doesn't exist")
query       'SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `table1` WHERE `table1`.`ndx` = 195  LIMIT 1'
```

Almost everything works, except the `save` method. A push in the right direction would help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You required [Manually Selecting a Database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset).

Looking on the error you gave, you should do something like this:

```
qs = table1.objects.using('DB1 ').filter(pk=id)
# just an example
```

In this example we are explicitly telling Django to locate `table1` in `DB1`.

Comment: Aamir, this is the output when I try to save an object via Admin 'add' facility. I don't have control over the code here. It fails on the `validate` function of `ForeignKey` class of `django.db.models.related`, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we cannot do anything to get relationships working between two tables in different mysql DBs. This is by design. Ticket [17875](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17875) has some info. We need to write code that works around this.